# Error while connecting to Phoenix ERROR 103 (08004): Unable to establish connection

Tags: macos, dbvisualizer

Am trying to establish connection to Phoenix, using DBVisualizer but getting below error

Followed steps give here 
https://community.hortonworks.com/articles/19016/connect-to-phoenix-hbase-using-dbvisualizer.html

After which getting error as below 
`ERROR 103 (08004): Unable to establish connection`

When checked the error log of DBVisualizer am seeing below things

```html
 

2019-07-22 12:53:18.890 INFO   903 [ExecutorRunner-pool-3-thread-1 - H.Ĵ] Exception while connecting Hbase
java.sql.SQLException: ERROR 103 (08004): Unable to establish connection.
        at org.apache.phoenix.exception.SQLExceptionCode$Factory$1.newException(SQLExceptionCode.java:422)
        at org.apache.phoenix.exception.SQLExceptionInfo.buildException(SQLExceptionInfo.java:145)
        at org.apache.phoenix.query.ConnectionQueryServicesImpl.openConnection(ConnectionQueryServicesImpl.java:392)
        at org.apache.phoenix.query.ConnectionQueryServicesImpl.access$300(ConnectionQueryServicesImpl.java:211)
        at org.apache.phoenix.query.ConnectionQueryServicesImpl$13.call(ConnectionQueryServicesImpl.java:2269)
        at org.apache.phoenix.query.ConnectionQueryServicesImpl$13.call(ConnectionQueryServicesImpl.java:2248)
        at org.apache.phoenix.util.PhoenixContextExecutor.call(PhoenixContextExecutor.java:78)
        at org.apache.phoenix.query.ConnectionQueryServicesImpl.init(ConnectionQueryServicesImpl.java:2248)
        at org.apache.phoenix.jdbc.PhoenixDriver.getConnectionQueryServices(PhoenixDriver.java:233)
        at org.apache.phoenix.jdbc.PhoenixEmbeddedDriver.createConnection(PhoenixEmbeddedDriver.java:135)
        at org.apache.phoenix.jdbc.PhoenixDriver.connect(PhoenixDriver.java:202)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
        at com.onseven.dbvis.h.B.D.ā(Z:1548)
        at com.onseven.dbvis.h.B.F$A.call(Z:1369)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ConnectionFactory.createConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:240)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ConnectionManager.createConnection(ConnectionManager.java:421)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ConnectionManager.createConnectionInternal(ConnectionManager.java:330)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HConnectionManager.createConnection(HConnectionManager.java:144)
        at org.apache.phoenix.query.HConnectionFactory$HConnectionFactoryImpl.createConnection(HConnectionFactory.java:47)
        at org.apache.phoenix.query.ConnectionQueryServicesImpl.openConnection(ConnectionQueryServicesImpl.java:390)
        ... 18 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:490)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ConnectionFactory.createConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:238)
        ... 23 more
Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Constructor threw an exception for org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcClientImpl
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.util.ReflectionUtils.instantiate(ReflectionUtils.java:54)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.util.ReflectionUtils.instantiateWithCustomCtor(ReflectionUtils.java:34)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcClientFactory.createClient(RpcClientFactory.java:64)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcClientFactory.createClient(RpcClientFactory.java:48)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation.<init>(ConnectionManager.java:638)
        ... 28 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:490)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.util.ReflectionUtils.instantiate(ReflectionUtils.java:46)
        ... 32 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.apache.hadoop.hbase.util.ClassSize
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.IPCUtil.<init>(IPCUtil.java:74)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.AbstractRpcClient.<init>(AbstractRpcClient.java:95)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcClientImpl.<init>(RpcClientImpl.java:1092)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcClientImpl.<init>(RpcClientImpl.java:1118)
```

Comment: The error shows that there are missing jar file(s) that needs to be loaded in the Tools->Driver Manager in DbVisualizer. I suggest you try connect and then open a support ticket in Help->Contact Support in DbVisualizer.

Answer (score 0):

I tried using Intellij and it is working fine.
Add all jars that are required by the phoenix driver and restart the tool.

Following jars I had added for IntelliJ

1. hbase-annotations
2. hbase-common
3. hbase-client
4. phoenix-hbase-client

I had added in the drivers of Intellij and restarted it.

Make sure you are using the proper version of JDK while connecting the Phoenix through tool.